# Mouse Events and FPS

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to record user's mouse movements by using canvas and javascript. Normally, each point is saved when there is a new mouse event from the browser, but obviously yhis causes problems when replaying them back.

For this reason, I had this idea of recording the mouse movement with constant frames per second but I don't really know how this can be achieved since mouse is event based (no way to request current position ?). Simply, I want to record mouse positions in a constant PFS to play them back with a constant FPS again.. **How can I achieve this "constant frames per second"  for event based mouse position?**

I'm pretty sure this question has a simple answer.. As a long-time flash user, frames were one of the main things served as a base to everything; Now I'm having hard times getting more abstract concepts I face everyday with canvas.

Thanks.

Comment: why does replaying browser events cause problems?

Comment: setup an mouse move listener, save the position in a variable each time it fires. than in your loop you grab the values from this variable.

Comment: To "replay" the movement in the same speed (behavior), I wanted to get the mouse positions in defined intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe the **problem** of saving all points is performance degradation of the browser.

But Even in flash you might have had to do that. Nothing is different here.

- In Flash you might have added mouse move event as a listener.

  In JS too you could attach mousemove handler to the object directly.
- In Flash, You have the fps or you use Timer Class for time events.

  In JS you have setInterval & setTimeout for the same.

You might gain nothing from this, But again, If you wish to keep the similar logic of updating the mouse coordinates, here is how :

JS needs time interval in milliseconds, so

```
interval = 1000 / fps;
```

Here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKhbc/) I brewed up for you.